# Putting Tags in order on the main site

Tags: discussion, tags

The point of this post is to put some order in the tags of the main site. Suggestions can be done here instead of spreading on multiples questions. You can suggest to create synonym, merging tags, or anything else related to tag management.

The goal is not to have the least number of tags possible but to have an good system were users can find information easily with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Can I suggest a separate answer here for each proposal so we can vote and comment on each separately. I agree with many but not all

Comment: What Tim B said. Also, keep substring matching in mind. We don't need synonyms for *every* possible variant of a tag. See for example here: [Tag synonym vs. renaming](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1689/29)

Answer (score 4):

<strike>[delude](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delude) as a synonym of [psychology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) - or deleted.</strike> $\to$ Delete the [delude](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delude) tag.

I removed it from [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23073/would-it-be-possible-to-excavate-a-planet-and-mine-it-without-indigenous-citizen) yesterday, which was about confusing in-universe people. I don't really see how it could be useful. <strike>It was suggested in chat that [psychology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) would be better, and I can't see [delude](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delude) coming in useful anywhere.</strike>

Comment: Delete it.  It's very specific and not central to world-building.  (Also, it loses points for being a (non-gerundive) verb.)

Answer (score 4):

Delete [religion-war](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion-war) as duplicates of [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare).

It was used with only one question, [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87837/how-to-prevent-religion-war-in-country-with-more-than-one-religion), which already had the [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) and [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) tags.  I have already removed the redundant tag from the question.

Comment: "Delete" should be changed to "merge", so we don't leave the question "tagless".

Comment: @Vylix, no question was left tagless.

Answer (score 3):

Delete [powers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers) as a duplicate of [super-powers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-powers).

It was used with only one question, [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84327/a-humane-way-to-hold-a-group-of-elemental-manipulators-prisoner).  I have edited the question to use [super-powers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-powers).

Answer (score 2):

[strategy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) as a synonym of [tactics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics).

Comment: Why do we have either?  If they're military questions, us that tag.  If they're creature-design questions, use that.  And so on.

Comment: Also, strategy and tactics are [different things](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/29418/8816), regardless of how the terms have been used here so far.

Comment: I think the questions we have so far would either fall into tag:warfare or are better without these tags. But I'm not sure they are 100% useless.

Comment: The distinction between the two tags is clear in my mind but I'm not sure how clear it is to other people.  (I haven't look through the questions for each tag either.)

Comment: [Non-warfare strategy question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/25072/2113).  The other seven are warfare questions.  [Non-warfare tactics question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/13679/2113).  And the other seven are warfare questions.

Answer (score 2):

Delete [niven-ring](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/niven-ring) as a duplicate of [dyson-ring](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dyson-ring).

It was used with only one question: [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93788/can-a-ringworld-have-a-moon).  I have edited the question to use [dyson-ring](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dyson-ring).